# Should i go for the EF 4.2 update through nuget or a standalone installer?

Tags: entity-framework, nuget

I would also like to know how the GAC works when i am using a standalone installer ?
Will it override my existing assembly int the project ?
if i have the express edition vs 2010 which does not  have nuget ,how do i best make use of these packages without breaking my existing stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking several different questions here.

Generally, the GAC always overrides the bin folder for a given version of an assembly. However, if the bin assembly has a different version, and your config file points to that version, it will use that instead of the GAC.

With VS Express that doesn't have the NuGet VSIX, using NuGet is definitely a bit harder. You need to get the [NuGet command line tool](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939), and run the install command to download packages, which you can then manually reference in your projects.

Comment: so, i need to have the command line tool for the express edition ...?? if i have an updated version in the bin assembly and not in the GAC then my project will use that instead of the GAC ?

Comment: Yes, I know it's not great, but at this time, we have no full support for Express (other than Web Express). And yes, it will use bin instead of GAC if you have a newer version.